# Concatenate string using .format

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, string-formatting, string-concatenation

I have some code similar to the following:

```
test_1 = 'bob'
test_2 = 'jeff'

test_1 += "-" + test_2 + "\n"
```

Output:

```
bob- jeff\n
```

I'd like to have the same functionality but using the `.format` method.

This is what I have so far:

```
test_1 = "{}{} {}\n".format(test_1, "-", test_2)
```

Which produces the same output, but is there a better/more efficient way of using `.format.` in this case?

Comment: Do you need to have the delimiter parameterized..could it be inside the format string? E.g.: `"{}- {}\n".format(test_1, test_2)`?..

Comment: Could also use `'- '.join((test_1, test_2)) + '\n'`

Answer (score 1):

`''.join` is probably fast enough and efficient.

```
'-'.join((test_1,test_2))
```

You can measure different methods using the `timeit` module. That can tell you which is fastest

This is an example of how `timeit` can be used:-

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))', number=10000)
0.8187260627746582
```

Comment: @tinySandy I don't see efficient way of using format, other that what Proletariat came up with. So i just posted another efficient way of doing this. :)

Comment: i wouldn't post anything since it's not related to what OP was asking

Comment: I appreciate the response but it's not using `.format` as @tinySandy said.

Comment: @Proletariat Im sorry, I did not read your question properly. I thought you were just asking if there was any other "better/more efficient" method.